# Binary compilation in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, opencl-c

Following [this github example](https://github.com/loganchien/opencl-examples). I have encountered a problem trying to use the pre built binary.

I successfully create my binary since I get the message `PLATFORM [Apple]  -->  SUCCESS (1)`.

But, when trying to use the binary, the function `clBuildProgram`, gives the error code `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`. ¿Any advice?

I'm using this code:

```
    int length = int_par[1];

    cl_int err;

    // Query platforms and devices
    cl_platform_id platform;
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);

    cl_device_id device;
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device, NULL);

    const cl_context_properties prop[] = {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)platform,
        0
    };

    // Create context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(prop, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);

    // Create program
    unsigned char* program_file = NULL;
    size_t program_size = 0;
    read_file1(&program_file, &program_size, "Kernel.clbin");

    cl_program program =
    clCreateProgramWithBinary(context, 1, &device, &program_size,
                              (const unsigned char **)&program_file,
                              NULL, &err);
   if(err!=CL_SUCCESS) Rprintf("clCreateProgramWithBinary!!!!\n%s\n", err_code(err));
err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    free(program_file);

    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        //char buffer[2048*3000];

        Rprintf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n%s\n", err_code(err));
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &len);
        //char *buffer = (char *) malloc(len);
        //char *buffer = (char*)calloc(len, sizeof(char));
        char *buffer =calloc(len,sizeof(char));
        //memset(buffer, 0, len);
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, len, buffer, NULL);
        SEP;

        Rprintf("Build Log:\n%s\n", buffer);
        SEP;
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS, sizeof(char), buffer, &len);
        Rprintf("Build Status:\n%s\n", buffer);
        SEP;
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_OPTIONS, sizeof(char), buffer, &len);
        Rprintf("Build Options:\n%s\n", buffer);
        SEP;
        //return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Besides, it is worth noting that this code worked fine in Sierra OS, but after I updated to Mojave, it did not anymore.

Comment: Are you trying to load a binary created with Sierra's OpenCL implementation on Mojave? That could be the source of your problem - I don't think there's any guarantee that a binary created with one OpenCL implementation is loadable with another.

Comment: I'm trying to do the whole process again. That is, the binary si successfully pre built in Mojave but when trying to use it with "clCreateProgramWithBinary", it fails as indicated.

Answer (score 2):

I had to ask for help in another platform and finally got the answer. Let me share it if someone needs it sometime:

"The main fix was in cl-compile program that changed what is saved to the binary file. It used to save the program created by the clBuildProgram method, and now it saves the program created by the clCompileProgram method.

Bottom line, if you want to save a compiled kernel, save it after a call to clCompileProgram method. On #Mojave you cannot build a program from binary if that binary was previously built by clBuildProgram."

Comment: You solved my problem, lasting for weeks...